# mysql find record between dates

Tags: php, mysql

```
SELECT 
    amount, 
    rh.honoraria_key, 
    rh.honoraria_name
FROM 
    xref_speaker_honoraria sh
    INNER JOIN xref_contract_speaker xcs ON (
        sh.contract_id = xcs.contract_id)
    INNER JOIN xref_contract_bureau xcb ON (
        xcs.contract_id = xcb.contract_id)
    INNER JOIN ref_contract c ON ( xcs.contract_id = c.contract_id )
    INNER JOIN ref_honoraria rh ON (
        sh.honoraria_id = rh.honoraria_id AND 
        rh.display_ext>0)
WHERE 
    sh.speaker_id = 888 AND 
    xcb.brand_id = 27
    AND CAST( c.`start` AS DATE ) < '2014-13-02' 
    AND CAST( c.`end` AS DATE ) > '2014-13-02' 
GROUP BY
    rh.honoraria_key
ORDER BY 
    rh.display_ext
```

I have the above mentioned query, it's not returning result because of a date issue. If I remove the `AND CAST( c.`end`AS DATE ) > '2014-13-02'` it works, but I want to get result between two dates. The DATA type of c.start and c.end is DATETYPE.

Any hint to fix this ?

Comment: Can you share some sample date and the result you're trying to achieve? Not sure I'm following...

Comment: If `start` and `end` are already Date Types, then why CAST as DATE?

Comment: because  I am comparing against date not date type, However its not working without date CAST also.

Comment: I don't see DATETYPE as a Date type in mysql: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-type-overview.html I'm rusty in mysql so I may be misunderstanding.

Comment: The datatype is datetime

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you are casting a DATE type to a DATE type, so I've removed that here. You can use the BETWEEN operator to check that the date you supplied is between the `start` and `end`

```
WHERE 
    sh.speaker_id = 888 AND 
    xcb.brand_id = 27
    '2014-13-02' BETWEEN `c`.`start` AND `c`.`end`
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you mean DATETIME. So just use DATE(c.`start`) instead of "CAST( c.`start` AS DATE )". And also use >= AND <= to be sure that you will get the first and the last day of the interval

Comment: I tried with DATE() and BETWEEN, but still not dropping results

Comment: Are you sure that you have records in the database that apply to the condition?